# apex form inserting data into extra table according to checkbox

Tags: oracle, forms, insert, oracle-apex

Goog morning
I have Apex page (form) based on table 'A'
and need to add non-database 'Checkbox',
if this checkbox is 'Y' , insert data into table 'B'
if checkbox is 'N', delete data from table 'B' if found

so I add process with type 'Execute Pl code'

```
if :P1_checkbox = 'Y' then
    delete from b where code = :P1_code ;
    insert into b (code , topic ) values ( :P1_code, :P1_topic) ;


elsif (:P1_checkbox = 'N' ) then 
    delete from b where topic = :P1_code ;

end if ;
```

but it's not working, not given errors
is there's another way!!

thanks in advance

so I add process with type 'Execute Pl code'

```
if :P1_checkbox = 'Y' then
    delete from b where code = :P1_code ;
    insert into b (code , topic ) values ( :P1_code, :P1_topic) ;


elsif (:P1_checkbox = 'N' ) then 
    delete from b where topic = :P1_code ;

end if ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process won't run *just because* you created it.

Usually, there's a button that **submits** the page; that action puts items' values into session state and you can reference them. Without it, maybe `P1_CHECKBOX` is actually `NULL` so `IF-THEN-ELSE` doesn't do anything as all conditions are *false*.

Note that process has condition which says **which button** (when pressed) runs that process - set it to the *submit* button.

---

Code itself looks OK. If you do what I wrote earlier and it still doesn't work, then run page in **debug mode** and review debug info afterwards; it'll tell you what Apex did.

Comment: thanks ,I needed to add the button to the process to work